# What is the purpose of mathematical research?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy, research

This is a bit of a soft and philosophical question, but what is the purpose of mathematical research? It seems to me that there is no end goal of mathematical research, because everything can be generalized, and every theorem that is proven simply leads to at least two more conjectures. Does mathematical research even have a purpose? Don't get me wrong, I love mathematics and mathematical literature, I just don't see the purpose of it.

Comment: What is the purpose of any research, besides advancing knowledge?

Comment: It gives mathematicians a job

Comment: "every theorem that is proven simply leads to at least two more conjectures" Really? Because I recently proved something interesting, but couldn't find these two conjectures yet. Maybe the existence of these conjectures is not so obvious.

Comment: Perhaps ["On teaching mathematics"](https://www.math.fsu.edu/~wxm/Arnold.htm) by V.I. Arnold would give you some insights.

Comment: See F.Bacon's [The Advancement of Learning (1605)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Advancement_of_Learning): "So that as Tennis is a game of no use in itself, but of great use in respect it maketh a quick eye, and a body ready to put itself in all positions, so, in the Mathematics the use which is collateral, an intervenient, is no less worthy, than that which is principle and intended."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's fun. It's beautiful. Sometimes it's useful. What's the purpose of poetry?